# How to get Data for an instruction from a program that uses an older version of anchor?

Tags: anchor, cpi

Im trying to CPI into marinade finance, but their codebase is in anchor 0.14, and im using anchor 0.24, so I cannot import the crate to get anything. I was able to find workarounds for everything else, but I cant find a workaround to get the Data part of the CPI

`marinade_finance::instruction::Deposit { lamports };`

How do I get this without importing the crate?

Answer (score 3):

If you build the crate with anchor-gen before importing it, this should clear up your issues. As noted in another question about CPIing to older client versions

1. use [anchor-gen](https://crates.io/crates/anchor-gen/0.1.2/dependencies) on the program
2. import the resulting crate in your cargo.toml file

This [should](https://twitter.com/simplyianm/status/1550978429281075201) clear up any errors

Answer (score 2):

If you have access to the repo, you can build it with `cargo build-bpf`, copy the `.so` file that the build generates, and add it as a dependency to your Cargo.toml:

`marinade = { path = "./dependencies/marinade/program", features=["no-entrypoint"] }`

Comment: How would that even work? The path there is a folder, not the file, and if I make a folder for the file, it will complain that it cannot find a cargo.toml for the workspace

Comment: the bit about building and copying the shared object is extraneous.  you only need to redirect cargo to a different source, be it a local directory or forked git repo. specification of dependencies in Cargo.toml is documented [here](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/specifying-dependencies.html)